# Expose localhost:8000 to EC2 public address

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a docker container running in my AWS EC2 instance, in localhost:8000. I can use `curl localhost:8000` and I can see the server returns the website, as expected.

Now, I want to be able to access this from my instance's public address. Is this possible?